# How can I put the limit for numbers in textfield for android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a textfield in android jetpack compose, so I want to put limit for numbers, for example; user can write only numbers from 1 to 10, is it possible to do it in jetpack compose?

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFieldComposable() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        label = { Text("Label") },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number))
 
}
```

Comment: Just to define a regex and use in the `onValueChange` with `if (it.matches(pattern))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a condition for that inside `onValueChange` like this:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFieldComposable() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val maxNumbers = 10
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { if (it.toInt() <= maxNumbers) text = it },
        label = { Text("Label") },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number))
 
}
```

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer, I mean if I put 11 it is not able to write, I want to just put number 1,2,3,...10, but user will not put 11

Comment: Yes that's what is going to happen

Comment: it put the text field limit like numbers limit, for example if u put   val maxNumbers = 2, u can only typing 99 max, u cannot write 100, but this question not about it, here I mean user only can write limited numbers like 1,2,3,4,5,...10. user will not able to write 11,12,13...

Comment: There's a KeyboardType.Digit. Otherwise, you need to check the number so that if it's bigger than 10, it won't be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicTextField(
                value = phoneNumber,
                onValueChange = { enterValue ->
                    phoneNumber =
                        if (enterValue.length <= 10) enterValue else enterValue.substring(0, 10)
                },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
                
            )
```

enjoy